Packed struct write into binary file fails
Here is the code:
  typedef struct packed {
    logic [15:0] marker;              // BYTE marker[2] -> Array of 2 bytes
    logic [15:0] length;              // WORD length -> 2 bytes (16 bits)
    logic [39:0] jfif;                // BYTE jfif[5] -> Array of 5 bytes
    logic [7:0]  major_vid;           // BYTE major_vid -> 1 byte (8 bits)
    logic [7:0]  minor_vid;           // BYTE minor_vid -> 1 byte (8 bits)
    logic [7:0]  pixel_density_unit;  // BYTE pixel_density_unit -> 1 byte (8 bits)
    logic [15:0] x_density;           // WORD x_density -> 2 bytes (16 bits)
    logic [15:0] y_density;           // WORD y_density -> 2 bytes (16 bits)
    logic [7:0]  x_thumbnail;         // BYTE x_thumbnail -> 1 byte (8 bits)
    logic [7:0]  y_thumbnail;         // BYTE y_thumbnail -> 1 byte (8 bits)
  } jm_app0_t;

...

 jpeg_file = $fopen("image.jpeg", "wb");

...

  jm_app0_t jm_app0;
    
  // Assign values to each field of the structure
  jm_app0.marker = 16'hE0FF;
  jm_app0.length = 16'h1000; // value 16 but byte order reversed
  
  // Assign JFIF string: "JFIF\0"
  jm_app0.jfif[39:32] = 8'h4A;        // 'J'
  jm_app0.jfif[31:24] = 8'h46;        // 'F'
  jm_app0.jfif[23:16] = 8'h49;        // 'I'
  jm_app0.jfif[15:8]  = 8'h46;        // 'F'
  jm_app0.jfif[7:0]   = 8'h00;        // '\0'
    
  // JFIF version
  jm_app0.major_vid = 8'h01;          // Major version 1
  jm_app0.minor_vid = 8'h01;          // Minor version 1
    
  // Pixels per inch
  jm_app0.pixel_density_unit = 8'h01; // Pixel density unit (1 = dots per inch)
  jm_app0.x_density =16'h6000;        // X density = 96 DPI
  jm_app0.y_density =16'h6000;        // Y density = 96 DPI
    
  // Thumbnail pixel dimensions
  jm_app0.x_thumbnail = 8'h00;        // No X thumbnail
  jm_app0.y_thumbnail = 8'h00;        // No Y thumbnail
  
  $fwrite(jpeg_file, "%u", jm_app0);

I have concluded that I must provide some format string and I believe that "%u" is the correct string. However, the data that is printed into the file is as follows that I got using HxD:
FF E0 00 00 46 4A 00 10 01 00 46 49 00 60 01 01 00 00 00 60

I should be getting this:
FF E0 00 10 4A 46 49 46 00 01 01 01 00 60 00 60 00 00

Not only are SystemVerilog string format features quite pathetic, the file I/O is also primitive. I am just trying to write a packed sturct into a binary file and it failed.
Edit:
I decided to use %s as the format string. I have also flipped the 16 bit data fields so they write the correct way around when using %s.
jm_app0_t jm_app0;

// Assign values to each field of the structure
// jm_app0.marker[0] = 8'hFF;          // Marker 0xFF
// jm_app0.marker[1] = 8'hE0;          // Marker 0xE0
jm_app0.marker = 16'hFFE0;
jm_app0.length = 16'h0010; // value 16 but byte order reversed

// Assign JFIF string: "JFIF\0"
jm_app0.jfif[39:32] = 8'h4A;            // 'J'
jm_app0.jfif[31:24] = 8'h46;            // 'F'
jm_app0.jfif[23:16] = 8'h49;            // 'I'
jm_app0.jfif[15:8]  = 8'h46;            // 'F'
jm_app0.jfif[7:0]   = 8'h00;            // '\0'

// JFIF version
jm_app0.major_vid = 8'h01;          // Major version 1
jm_app0.minor_vid = 8'h01;          // Minor version 1

// Pixels per inch
jm_app0.pixel_density_unit = 8'h01; // Pixel density unit (1 = dots per inch)
jm_app0.x_density = 16'h0060;        // X density = 96 DPI
jm_app0.y_density = 16'h0060;        // Y density = 96 DPI

// Thumbnail pixel dimensions
jm_app0.x_thumbnail = 8'h00;        // No X thumbnail
jm_app0.y_thumbnail = 8'h00;        // No Y thumbnail

$fwrite(jpeg_file, "%s", jm_app0);

Now I get this which is still wrong:
FF E0 20 10 4A 46 49 46 20 01 01 01 60 20 60 20 20 20

It is clear that when I write using %s, the value 0x00 gets replaced with 0x20. I think that the %s must not be used at all since it could possible treat 0x0a character as an actual line end (called \n in C/C++) and mess with it.
What really is the solution to this broken language?

The question is, what is the correct way to write a packed struct into binary file? The data appearing in the file does not match what is present in the struct. I checked the struct in wave view. I am using windows with QuestaSim.

Your choice of words is pathetic.

This has nothing to do with packed structures. Its the same as if you wrote
$fwrite(jpeg_file, "%u", 144'h_e0ff10004a46494600010101600060000000);

Your problem is %u (unformatted) writes in 32-bit words, which is 4 bytes at a time. Your bit vector only has 18 bytes, so it padded 2 bytes to the vector with 16'h0 and wrote 5 32-bit words.
SystemVerilog is a hardware description and verification language for digital design. If you need other functionality to integrate with your host operating system, you can pass your vector to C using the VPI or DPI interfaces and write it out any way you want. Or you can accept the way $fwrite works and move on.

After lot of trial and error I found the solution. I am not sure why no one on the internet has discussed this specific topic before.

How about posting your solution as another answer.
